# How to set LIMIT property with redis ft.SEARCH in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, redis

code

```
  client.ft.SEARCH('license-index-json',"@\\$\\" + ".reservedForApplicationName:GSTest",{
    LIMIT: {
      from: 0,
      to: 1
    }
  })
```

Error

Argument of type '["license-index-json", string, { LIMIT: { from: number; to: number; }; }]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[index: string, query: string, options?: SearchOptions] | [options: CommandOptions, index: string, query: string, options?: SearchOptions]'.
Type '["license-index-json", string, { LIMIT: { from: number; to: number; }; }]' is not assignable to type '[options: CommandOptions, index: string, query: string, options?: SearchOptions]'.
Type at position 0 in source is not compatible with type at position 0 in target.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'CommandOptions'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ readonly [symbol]: true; }'.ts(2345)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/packages/search/lib/commands/SEARCH.ts

use `from` and `size`, not `from` and `to`

```js
client.ft.SEARCH('idx', 'query', {
  LIMIT: {
    from: 0,
    size: 1
  }
});
```